# How to split a cell of many numbers by group of 3-3 in each next cells?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

As above image I have a column which consists many numbers separated by comma. I need to split those numbers by group of 3-3 in each next cell.

Comment: Do you actually have access to VBA here?

Comment: This seems like a strange requirement. Why do you need three comma-separated values in a cell, instead of three cells with one value each?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: its buisness requirment and i have tried text to column. @jsheeran

Comment: Use find to locate the 3rd comma and separate - first set with left etc

Comment: hi can u just give me an syntax or example @SolarMike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, brutal but does work:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1)+1)-1)
```

You can play with MID() and RIGHT() to get others....

See
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give a try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim str As String
    Dim Appears As Long, i As Long, Times As Long, LastColumn As Long, StartPoint As Long, EndPoint As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        str = .Range("A1").Value & ","

        Times = 0

        StartPoint = 1

        For i = 1 To Len(str)

            If Mid(str, i, 1) = "," Then

                Times = Times + 1

                If CDbl(Times / 3) = Round(CDbl(Times / 3)) Then

                    EndPoint = i

                    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                    .Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value = Mid(str, StartPoint, EndPoint - StartPoint)

                    StartPoint = EndPoint + 2

                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```