# Separating Comma List into Cells with Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I have a comma separated list (e.g.: `dog, car, truck`) and need to separate each word into a cell, going vertically down a column, using a formula.

Input: dog, car, truck

Output:

```
dog
car
truck
```

How can this be accomplished with a formula?

Comment: Have a look at left(), mid(), right() and find(). Showing what you have attempted is also good. Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55536475/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your value in A1, put this in the first cell and copy down:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*999+1,999))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this almost works. However, some of the words get split into two cells with this formula. How to fix this?

Comment: well you only showed one example.  It would only split if there is a comma.

Comment: using the example: exampleone, exampletwo, examplethree, examplefour, examplefive, examplesix, exampleseven, exampleeigght, examplenine, exampleten, exampleeleven, exampletwelve, examplethirteen, examplefourteen, examplefifteen, examplesixteen, exampleseventeen, exampleeighteen, examplenineteen, exampletwenty

the output splits on "examplenine" --> "examplenin" / "e" and "exampleseventeen" --> "exam" / "pleseventeen

Comment: Genius! Thank you!

Comment: @Zauberflöte please mark as correct by clicking the (√) check mark by the answer.