# Comma separated list into matched columns pairings

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I thought I was a decent Sheets jockey, but here's a toughie. I'd like to turn the left into the right using just a formula

[image: snap]

Sample also at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JgDZOV_K7SbOrCb27Z5K2XUBcrtq99GTCa3-BM2pOD0

The closest I found was this ([Separating Comma List into Cells with Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539475/separating-comma-list-into-cells-with-formula)) but it doesn't also do the matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative by [@Matt:King](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/12496685):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)*
 COLUMNS(SPLIT(B2:B, ",")), 1, 0)/ COLUMNS(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))+2,
 {ROW(A:A), A:A, TRIM(SPLIT(B:B, ","))}, MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)*
 COLUMNS(SPLIT(B2:B, ",")), 1, 0), COLUMNS(SPLIT(B2:B, ",")))*{0, 1}+{2, 3}),
 "where Col2 is not NULL"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B1:B, ","))<>"", "♠"&A1:A&"♦"&SPLIT(B1:B, ","), ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi player0, thanks so much for your help!

I got a somewhat different answer on the same question I had posed on the Google forums at the same time: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/12496685. I'm not skilled enough to be able to discern what the pros/cons are of each approach. Would you be able to help me figure this out? Going to do the same thing on the other post, linking this one :)

Thank you!

Misha

Comment: can't rly vouch for the other formula but both use TRIM so both are kinda limited coz TRIM can handle no more than 50000 characters per output. in worst scenario TRIM can be omitted from this formula if needed so this fx can scale up to and beyond 50000 rows. then there is QUERY which again both of them use. QUERY fx has increased processing slowdown the more rows query needs to process. on average this can be noticed beyond 20000 row margin. however, VLOOKUP will surely increase processing time on a larger scale combined with QUERY.

Comment: basically what this formula does is: combining every comma-separated value from B with the value from A column and unique symbol. then it compresses all those combined values into one single cell from which it splits into rows and columns via those unique symbols creating the desired output.  pros: shorter and straightforward. ofc. if you by any chance find the other formula to be faster for you, then use the other one.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much player0! That's a great explanation, and I appreciate you taking the time.