# Search different columns and count specific values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

My Google Sheet looks like this:

[image]

I want the H , I and J columns to be filled of the data of the A:F columns.
The data will be inserted using a form.
Every row (A:F) is a day.
The C column separate the text items using the ",". It will be more than iron, glass or wood. This is just an example. The countries (G column) are pre-edited.

I want when a new day (row) is inserted to look for the iron, glass and wood that every country bought and if it finds the item to add 1 under the matched one, so I will know that France buys more glass than Iron and zero wood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**G7** cell:

```
={"countries"; "australia"; "america"; "greece"; "france"; "norway"; "edypt"; "russia"}
```

[image: 0]

**H7** cell:

```
={"glass","iron","wood"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G8:G="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(G8:G, 
 QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT({C7:C; F7:F}, ","))<>"", 
 "♦"&{A7:A; D7:D}&"♥"&SPLIT({C7:C; F7:F}, ",")&"♥", ), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♥"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), {2,3,4}, 0))*1))}
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yl2xVoNN1ooBvtaK-tlIOipDhAZL7RucoF6C9JvG2As/edit#gid=1529083)

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem is that the countries are more, about 450 countries and the items are about 80 and we continue adding.  I think this function will not work easy

Comment: can be modded to be autogenerated... can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: This is the sheet. I just made it for the question to stackoverflow. I haven't create it yet. My boss asked for it and Im trying to figure out how to create this

Comment: I was thinking for an array eg australia looking for this country between A:F and if finds it look for glass and if its true add 1 and so on. Then australia will look for iron and then for wood. Then next row, america and so on.

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yl2xVoNN1ooBvtaK-tlIOipDhAZL7RucoF6C9JvG2As/edit#gid=1529083

Comment: I did copy the formula and it doesnt work.It gives me error and what are the hearts and the diamonds ? I changed all the 8s (eg C8:C) to 2 (eg C2:C) to use it to my example, and it doesnt work at all.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yfgCwNdJTq0QPWr6_zusdDKDrASZbkcurUo0vA_Qa2Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I saw another answer of yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593084/comma-separated-list-into-matched-columns-pairings/57597791#57597791    and i like the way you solved it. Is it possible to do this for my case ? I mean to "read" all the data from the columns and to transpose the way I want without pre editing anything.

Comment: yes that is possible. tho, I was in understanding that you have list of countries in G column that are not listed in range A:F

Comment: see H7: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yl2xVoNN1ooBvtaK-tlIOipDhAZL7RucoF6C9JvG2As/edit#gid=772204794