# How can I get this formula to grab values between the commas?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

Here is a screenshot of and a link to my test spreadsheet. It makes the requirements very clear:

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rZr2zHaSkff9SFpwpx83_4TawruotA1jhOKqW6uYDz0/edit?usp=sharing

The formula I have come up with is very close to what I need, but "linkText" is a placeholder for the value of the array item. Here is my formula:

```
=if(A2="","","<a href='https://samplewebsite.com/search?q=" & trim(lower(substitute(A2,",","'>linkText</a>, <a href='https://samplewebsite.com/search?q="))) & "'>linkText</a>")
```

Comment: If you put the formula in the body of the question that would help. I avoid Google as much as possible but I'm curious about this question.

Comment: That was my last edit ;)

Comment: My first thought is a regular expressions, and it turns out Google Sheets does support that. I'll give it a few tries and report back. Ack maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### try:

```
=index(join(","&char(10), SUBSTITUTE($B$1, "linkText", split(A3, ","))))
```

Drag down to column.

**Result:**
[image]

First using SPLIT to split the strings between comma from the column A. Then using SUBSTITUTE to find the string "linkText" from the text in B1 and replace it with the strings from the returned strings from the split function. Then joining them all together.

NOTE: Just keep the reference string in a fixed cell in your sheet.   `<a href='https://samplewebsite.com/search?q=linkText'>linkText</a>` to be used in the formula. As seen in above screenshot it is fixed in cell B1.

### Alternate Solution using ArrayFormula:

You can also use it with arrayformula so you only have to put it in the first row and no need to drag down the formula to the column, it will automatically be expanded down just make sure to clear the cells below or it will throw an error.

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(substitute(transpose(query(transpose(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ","))<>"", "♦<a href='https://samplewebsite.com/search?q="&SPLIT(A2:A, ",")&"'>"&SPLIT(A2:A, ",")&"</a>", )),,9^9)), "♦", char(10)), "^\s", ""))
```

**Result:**
[image]

You may also have a look in below references for more information.

References:

- [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en)
- [SPLIT](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/split-function/)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)
- [Comma separated list into matched columns pairings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593084/comma-separated-list-into-matched-columns-pairings)

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you! (I went with Option #1)

Comment: @MichaelSwarts You're welcome, glad to know it's resolved!