# Search Name in 2 cells and return the value in third cell if the name matches

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to create a formula in my Google Sheet where I put the name of any person in one cell then the data related to that person/'s should populate against that cell (in a single cell only)

[I'm attaching an image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKPTg.png)
Request to share the possible solution for the above problem.

Thank you

I tried Vlookup but it is not showing up all the details and not working as well.

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($E$2=$A$2:$A$12,$B$2:$B$12,""))

I tried the above Formula but it didn't work.

Comment: Give a look at this answer,i think it solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593084/comma-separated-list-into-matched-columns-pairings

Comment: Thank you for your response but I want the opposite of it.(Please see the image attached above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP just returns the first occurrence, altought you can use TEXTJOIN and FILTER to make that. Take a look at that:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;FILTER(B2:B12;E2=A2:A12))
```

You can read more about that functions here:

- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en
- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en

Comment: Thank you so much @luismsobotyk, it worked and thank you for sharing the links as well.